# What can be done to increase the accuracy of an op amps gain?

Tags: electrical-engineering

When working with op-amp circuits such as non-inverting, inverting, and summing amplifiers there is always some discrepancy between theoretical and experimental gain. I know a cause of this can be due to bias currents and input offset voltage. What is done to overcome these problems and increase the accuracy of the gain of an op-amp? More specifically for an inverting amplifier both by circuitry and from inside the op-amps.

Comment: This is *very* circuit dependent. You might want to ask about one specific type of circuit. Also, don't forget about bandwidth. Transimpedance amps are the most interesting ones I think. Also you might want to specify if you are asking about the circuitry around the opamp or inside (because that can also be done, sometimes much more effectively but as an end user you have little control and is also more complicated to understand)

Comment: depending on the op amp, you can also try to play with your op amp voltage supplies.  results will likely be circuit dependent.

Comment: This is a very broad question. What has your research turned up so far?

Comment: The open-circuit gain of an op-amp is >100,000.  It is only by feedback that the gain can be controlled.